# Swing: Adding listener to a component and ALL its decoration?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, events

Can I add a listener (let's say **MouseAdapter**) to a Swing component
and all it's **internal decoration components**?

So that when a JInternalFrame is moved by the mouse
*(by dragging its window title bar)*, it would give me following events:

- **mousePressed** event,
- **mouseDragged** event,
- **mouseReleased** event.

Currently, I receive **none** of the above events when dragging
JInternalFrame.

*I hope there is some standardized solution, but I couldn't find any.*

**EDIT:**
Some people suggest using **ComponentListener**, but that wouldn't do for
me. I need to know, **when** the user **stops dragging** (mouseReleasedEvent),
**not** when the component moves.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add a listener to all a container's components. `getComponents` and add the listener. You should be able to manage to do this recursively. You can also use `ContainerListener` to check for adding and removing components.

However, `MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` behave strangely in that the event normally bubbles up to the parent, but does not do so if a listener is present (how is that for hopeless design?).

Your choices are:

- Recursively adding listeners (bad, see above)
- Adding listeners to specific components (fragile)
- Adding a "glass pane" (a messy hack)
- Adding an `AWTEventListener` to `Toolkit` (requires permissions)
- Pushing an `EventQueue` and checking through events (doesn't work of Opera and Safari apparently; stops system copy-and-paste and applet dragging from working)
- Use `ComponentListener`?

Comment: Tried: glass pane doesn't receive necessary events. I think I'm going write own draggable component (already done once)

Comment: A glass pane on the contents area of the internal frame (obviously) wont work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you mean glass pane of the parent of JInternalFrame.
Why it's a messy hack?

Comment: Glass panes are always a hack. All that event forwarding. Eurgh. In 1.6, popup were moved from glass panes (which caused a few issues) to awt event listener.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how it **could** be done, but something tells me, it's a **dirty hack** ;)

**Well, it works, but who can give me the guarantee that it works everywhere?**

```
// ctor goes here {

InternalFrameUI thisUI = getUI();
((BasicInternalFrameUI) thisUI).getNorthPane()
    .addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseListener());

// }
```

**NorthPane** turns out to be the window title bar.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a [MouseMotionListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html) instead of a [MouseListener](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html).

Comment: MouseAdapter implements both, and I add it using
addMouseListener(...) and addMouseMotionListener(...)

Answer (score 0):

In the [JInternalFrame API documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html), it says:

> Generally, you add JInternalFrames to
>   a JDesktopPane. The UI delegates the
>   look-and-feel-specific actions to the
>   DesktopManager  object maintained by
>   the JDesktopPane.

Maybe you should add your listener to the JDesktopPane.

Answer (score 0):

MouseListener/MouseMotionListener wont detect when dragging a JInternalFrame. Your best bet here to detect movement is using a ComponentListener on the JInternalFrame itself.

Comment: The ComponentListener fires the event "componentMoved", but I need to know when the user begin and end the dragging operation. The user could let the mouse button pressed but don't move the commponent. ComponentListener wouldn't tell me that the mouse button is still pressed.

Comment: I realise that, but not quite sure how you would acomplish that so this was the best I could do. Out of curiosity why do you need to know this?